# How to make everything in action bar in black?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

My current app's theme is inheriting from the default "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar".

I'm having issues trying to find the right attributes to make everything in my action bar in black (up button, app title etc.). This material components theme defaults the text to be in white.

Does anyone know how to do this in my themes xml?

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute on your styles.xml:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#000000</item>
```

for more details you can see the doc:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#colorControlHighlight

**EDIT:**

You can create a theme for you tabbar, like:

```
<style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimaryLight</item>       
</style>
```

So you apply it on your tabbar:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" />
```

Comment: I'm either doing something wrong or this is not working. I added that item by itself within my themes.xml and it doesn't work. I then added <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyAppBarStyle</item> and     <style name="MyAppBarStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
    </style> in my styles and that doesn't work either.